# select in select mysql about subquery

Tags: mysql

i have a query like this, which is the best method to solve this query?

```
SELECT month(createdat), year(createdat), sum(quantity) from (
SELECT 
    sum(omd.quantity), omd.createdat
FROM
    order_match_detail omd, order_match om
WHERE
   omd.order_match_id = om.id
   AND omd.product_id = 144
   and om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
        AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            1
        FROM
            order_match_detail omd1,
            order_match om1
        WHERE
            omd1.order_match_id = om1.id
                AND om1.createdAt < om.createdAt
                AND omd1.product_id = 144
                AND om1.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8))) z
group by month(createdat), year(createdat) order by 2 asc, 1 asc;
```

it says when i run this query `Error Code : 1054. Unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list'`
this was expected result (based on the fiddle) where product_id = 144 and order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)

```
    +--------+------+---------------+
    | Month  | Year | Sum(Quantity) |
    +--------+------+---------------+
    |      1 | 2019 |            50 |
    |      2 | 2019 |            34 |
    +--------+------+---------------+
```

Sample data set and fiddle of same

```
CREATE TABLE order_match ( id INT(11), 
                                       createdAt datetime, 
                                       order_status_id INT(10)
                               );
INSERT INTO order_match  VALUES
(1,'2019-01-01',4),
(2,'2019-01-10',5),
(3,'2019-01-20',6),
(4,'2019-02-10',7),
(5,'2019-02-15',4),
(6,'2019-02-21',5),
(7,'2019-01-02',6),
(8,'2019-01-11',8),
(9,'2019-01-18',7),
(10,'2019-02-06',5);

CREATE TABLE order_match_detail (id int(11),
                                 order_match_id INT(11), quantity int(11), product_id int(11));
INSERT INTO order_match_detail VALUES 
(1, 1, 20, 144),
(2, 2, 30, 144), 
(3, 3, 24, 100), 
(4, 4, 34, 144), 
(5, 5, 43, 120), 
(6, 6, 34, 144), 
(7, 7, 23, 442), 
(8, 8, 23, 24), 
(9, 9, 24, 12), 
(10,10, 24, 24);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81e3aa/2

Comment: I don't understand why are there are two separate tables. If each id can only have one corresponding order_match_id, then why bother splitting them? When defining a table you MUST always define the PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really making a meal of this... :-(

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(o.createdat,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
     , SUM(quantity) total 
  FROM order_match o 
  JOIN order_match_detail d 
    ON d.order_match_id = o.id 
 WHERE o.order_status_id IN (4,5,6,8)
   AND d.product_id = 144
 GROUP 
    BY yearmonth;
+-----------+-------+
| yearmonth | total |
+-----------+-------+
| 2019-01   |    50 |
| 2019-02   |    34 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the first sub-query. Your column is not called "quantity" but "sum(omd.quantity)". You have to give an alias to the columns in the subquery like so:

```sql
SELECT month(createdat), year(createdat), sum(quantity) from (
SELECT 
    sum(omd.quantity) AS quantity, omd.createdat
FROM ...
```

€dit: With that out of the way i solved your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81e3aa/5/0

HOWEVER: Though it creates your desired result it does not take into account this condition:

```sql
om1.createdAt < om.createdAt
```

Changing the data resulted in other values, where i think the result should stay the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88c2e1/1/0

What do you think?

Comment: the resultl was wrong, seems like without group by, just not same with expected result, but thankyou for your answer

Comment: the result is not true sir, check my expected results thankyou